# MUI v5 Grid - space grid items evenly (justifyContent: space-evenly)

Tags: material-ui, grid, justify

I want to achieve a box of a minimum height of 500px and three cards vertically centered within this box.
The cards shall be spaced evenly but `justifyContent="space-evenly"` is not affecting at all.

Im using MUI v5 (`"@mui/material": "5.10.4"`).

What am I doing wrong?

```
<Grid
    container
    spacing={0}
    direction="column"
    alignItems="center"
    justifyContent="center"
    sx={{
        minHeight: 500,
        backgroundColor: '#f1f2f3',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        },
        }}
>

    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="space-evenly" alignItems="center" sx={{pt:10, pb:10}}>
            <Grid item>
                <Card sx={{
                    width: 300,
                    height: 400,
                    backgroundColor: "#030814",
                }}>
                </Card>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <Card sx={{
                    width: 300,
                    height: 400,
                    backgroundColor: "#030814",
                }}>
                </Card>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <Card sx={{
                    width: 300,
                    height: 400,
                    backgroundColor: "#030814",
                }}>
                </Card>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that in you parent `Grid` container the `direction="column"` is causing the issue. Either you need to set it to `direction="row"` or just remove it.

Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pond-nldi9m)

```
<Grid
    container
    spacing={0}
    // direction="column"  // This is causing the issue
    alignItems="center"
    justifyContent="center"
    sx={{
        minHeight: 500,
        backgroundColor: '#f1f2f3',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        },
        }}
> 
...
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Also for the codesandbox!